# Checkout cart remove item not updating

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart

I've taken over a project from someone else and am having trouble fixing a bug on the checkout/cart page. When an item is added and you're redirected to `domain.com/checkout/cart` when you try to remove the item, the page seems to reload but the item is still there until you manually refresh. Sometimes have the same issue with adding an item, won't appear until you refresh the page.

I've tried debugging in `app/design/frontend/rwd/<theme>/template/checkout/cart.phtml` but when trying to `var_dump($this->getItems())` the page hangs and eventually crashes. I'm trying to see at what point the system recognises that items have been added/removed. How else can I go about outputting the items currently in the cart?

I have the other code that is generally linked to update not working

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form_before') ?>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">
    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

It seems to be able to retrieve `getItems()` but unable to dump the returned data.

```
<?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Try giving unlimited memory limit by using the following
ini_set('memory_limit','16M');
Let me know if works. \

Comment: @Ponsundar It's currently set at `256M` and still hangs

Comment: In general, you cannot `var_dump` a collection, the data can be enormous, and it's generally not very useful for debugging purpose. The delete action happens in _app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php_. Look for `public function deleteAction()` and add `$this->_getSession()->addNotice('item count='.$this->_getCart()->getItemsCount());` before the last line `$this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getUrl('*/*'));` You can also add the notice at the beginning to see if the item count reduces.

Comment: I just noticed there is a `ajaxDeleteAction` for _minicart_. You should check what is the URL for the delete icon in your cart page. The default URL should look something like this _domain.com/checkout/cart/delete/id/<some number>/uenc/<some string>_. If it is not like the default, then you should fix it.

Comment: @kiatng will have a look at the file, the remove button seems to follow the exact format you posted

Comment: @kiatng I added the lines and upon clicking the remove button it doesn't display the notice, it does show it on manual refresh though... (it does work locally)

Comment: @Bankzilla Could be cache. Ask your hosting company if the cache is enabled. If it is, disable it.

Comment: @kiatng seems like it is a cache issue, still trying to debug it before I contact the hosting company. The whole site seems to be caching, I've tried adding `setCacheLifetime` in local.xml and enabling `setEsiOptions` in checkout.xml but nothing is working so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after debugging every single cache possible it actually turned out to be browser caching the site, this was happening for everybody that visited the site, why I still have no idea.

I added the following in `.htaccess` which seems to have resolved the issue

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|php)>
    FileETag None
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

You never `var_dump` these objects. They're too long and will eat your memory. You should use `Mage::log` for just what you need to know.

```
<?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
    <?php Mage::log($_item->getId()); // or getName(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Also, you probably want to check some debugging tools, like [`xdebug`](http://xdebug.org/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

**CommerceBug** by Alan Storm can be very helpful in these cases: http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/commerce-bug-2.

Like Pedram wrote: **Never** use var_dump() to dump collections. Your system will freeze as collections generally are huge data objects. Instead, iterate over the collection and use Mage::log().

Or better, have a look at CommerceBug.